# Recreating ESRI projection/transformations in GDAL/OSR/OGR

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, gdal, open-source-gis, osr

How can I make sure that the coordinate transformations that I am applying using GDAL/OSR match transformations in ESRI/ArcGIS?

Specifically the ArcPy geometry function, `projectAs` when taking in the name of a transformation.   When ArcGIS reprojects from ITRF2014 to NAD83(CSRS)v7 (EPSG:8255) with the transformation "ITRF2014_To_NAD_1983_CSRS_v7_7par", a point is generated ~30 ft away from the point generated by GDAL/OSR:

**Original coordinate**: -74.442799450000, 41.406811727778
ESRI point after transform: -74.4427951819612, 41.4068026527349
OGR point after transform: -74.44281012167299, 41.40671904426617

[image]

Code used to generate the ODR point:

```
itrf = osr.SpatialReference()
itrf.ImportFromProj4('GEOGCS["ITRF2014",DATUM["International_Terrestrial_Reference_Frame_2014",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG",9000]]')

to_nad = osr.SpatialReference()
to_nad.ImportFromEPSG(8255)

opts = osr.CoordinateTransformationOptions()
opts.SetOperation("ITRF2014_To_NAD_1983_CSRS_v7_7par")
transformer = osr.CreateCoordinateTransformation(itrf, to_nad, opts)

outpoint = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
outpoint.AddPoint(*test_coords)
outpoint.AssignSpatialReference(itrf)
outpoint.Transform(transformer)
```

Code used to generate the Esri point

```
ITRF_SPATIAL_REF = arcpy.SpatialReference('ITRF2014.prj')
NAD_SPATIAL_REF= arcpy.SpatialReference(8255)

longitude = test_coords[0]
latitude = test_coords[1]
point = arcpy.Point(
    longitude,
    latitude
)
return_point = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, ITRF_SPATIAL_REF).projectAs(NAD_SPATIAL_REF, "ITRF2014_To_NAD_1983_CSRS_v7_7par")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messaging the gdal-dev mailing list, I received this answer which resolved my issue:

You've likely used the coordinate order wrong. GDAL 3 honours by default authority (EPSG) axis order, so for EPSG this means lat/lon for geographic CRS.

So either switch your coordinate, or call `itrf.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)` and `to_nad.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)`

With that, you'll get the same results as Esri software

```
>>> print(outpoint)
POINT (-74.442810121673 41.4067190442662 0)
```